# Best approach for an independent scrolling cells in a grid-like view?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, viewgroup

I've been racking my brain on this for a few days and I'm unsure the best method to use to acheive this

I basically want an Android View that has a grid-like view, but I can independently scroll the cells of this grid both vertically and horizontally. I am going to need the ability to click the "cells" (which need to be views of some description). I have a [potato-quality drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo2XY.jpg) to try and better explain what I mean :)

I've implemented this so far and it's sort of working using a ViewGroup, and essentially adding all the views and calculating where they should be, and then using the `onTouch` event to handle moving the views (based on the `dX` and `dY` of the view, but it doesn't feel stable at all, and the events are randomly picked up (because i'm trying to decide if the ViewGroup should handle the `onTouch` event of the "cell" (view) should handle it in the `onInterceptTouch`, which isn't really a good way of doing this I know. I'm at the stage where I need to completely re-write it I think, but that got me thinking is this the way it should be being done do you think? I thought about using a RecyclerView and some sort of custom LayoutManager to handle the movement of the cells, which in my mind sounds like a better way of doing it, but I don't really know how I would start using that and how it would meet all the requirements of this view. Even so, is this the better way of doing it?

Thanks